# JqGrid reposition the of Add button

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jqgrid

Am a beginner in jqGrid ,where am using navGrid, for Add(Which is used for File Upload), when i click on add button, it pops up a Modal dialog in top, leftside of the page.its very uneasy to go the top and come again is there any way to position the Add dialog and it should show up next to the + button ?

```
    jQuery(table).jqGrid('navGrid',pager,{edit:false,add:true,del:false,search:false,refresh:true,cloneToTop:true},{},{addCaption:'Add',width:500,recreateForm: true,reloadAfterSubmit:false,closeAfterAdd:true,closeAfterEdit: true, closeOnEscape:true, afterSubmit : UploadAttachedFile });
```

Comment: You want to re-position the `add` button or the `Modal Dialog` which appears after cliking on `add` button?

Comment: @Bhushan this is Add Button Code, where the popup goes to the top of page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change position of Add dialog inside of [afterShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback. For example you can use [jQuery UI Position](http://jqueryui.com/position/) to do this.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddDialogPosition.htm) use the following code

```js
var $grid = $("#list");

...

$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {del:false}, {}, {
    afterShowForm: function ($form) {
        $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").position({
            of: "#add_" + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id),
            at: "left bottom",
            my: "right top"
        });
    }
});
```

and the results looks like on the picture below

[image]

You can change the values of `at` and `my` properties of `position` to have exact results which you need.

Comment: This answer is more proper than my answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add this to your code of `Add` button

```
top:400,left:20
```

your code should look like:

```
jQuery(table).jqGrid('navGrid',pager,{edit:false,add:true,del:false,search:false,refresh:true,cloneToTop:true},
    {},
    {
        addCaption:'Add',
        width:500,
        recreateForm: true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:false,
        closeAfterAdd:true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        afterSubmit : UploadAttachedFile,
        top:400,    //position from top
        left:20    //position from left
    });
```

Comment: No, Still it appears the same way..!!

Comment: @user2285151 can you post code of your grid? or any sample small example?